# How do you draw a dot about 7 pixels wide in mspaint?

Tags: windows

I do not understand this, I am sure I have in the past clicked the button to draw a dot and selected a size and got a different sized dot. But it's not happening for me at the moment.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you click brushes choose the first brush then the sizes go a bit bigger than when clicking the pencil as you did. The first brush is also the default for when starting mspaint which explains having done it so many times but not knowing how / not knowing what option it was. Notice that the sizes go bigger than the pencil does.

[image]